# what wrong with this paper and rock mini game?

Tags: javascript

It return no error but I sense something wrong in codeacademy's console. It return single string - "rock", "paper" or "scissors". I couldn't detect what's wrong.

```
var userChoice = prompt("Do you choose rock, paper or scissors?");
var computerChoice = Math.random();
if (computerChoice < 0.34) {
    computerChoice = "rock";
} else if(computerChoice <= 0.67) {
    computerChoice = "paper";
} else {
    computerChoice = "scissors";
}

function compare(choice1, choice2){
    if(choice1 == choice2) return "The result is a tie!";

    if(choice1 == "rock"){
        if(choice2 =="scissors") return "rock wins" 
        else return "paper wins";
    }

        if(choice1 == "paper"){
        if(choice2 =="scissors") return "scissors wins" 
        else return "paper wins";
    }

        if(choice1 == "scissors"){
        if(choice2 =="paper") return "scissors wins" 
        else return "rock wins";
    }

    compare(userChoice, computerChoice);

}
```

Any bug in the logic and the program flow?

Comment: You never call compare.

Comment: You have the call to `compare` inside the definition of `compare`.  Is that a typo?  Otherwise, it's a pretty massive bug.

Comment: my bad, didn't notice that! but even I call the function outside the function scope, the result is always rock wins if choice1 is rock

Comment: I can't for the life of me make your code **not** work once you pull the compare() out of the function definition. Even hardcoding the choice 'rock' instead of using the prompt results in a relatively even distribution of ties, wins for them them, or wins for me.

Answer (score 1):

```
var userChoice = prompt("Do you choose rock, paper or scissors?");
var computerChoice = Math.random();
if (computerChoice < 0.34) {
    computerChoice = "rock";
} else if(computerChoice <= 0.67) {
    computerChoice = "paper";
} else {
    computerChoice = "scissors";
}

function compare(choice1, choice2){
    if(choice1 == choice2) return "The result is a tie!";

    if(choice1 == "rock"){
        if(choice2 =="scissors") return "rock wins" 
        else return "paper wins";
    }

    if(choice1 == "paper"){
        if(choice2 =="scissors") return "scissors wins" 
        else return "paper wins";
    }

    if(choice1 == "scissors"){
        if(choice2 =="paper") return "scissors wins" 
        else return "rock wins";
    }
}

compare(userChoice, computerChoice);
```

You were calling compare() inside the definition of compare.

Answer (score 0):

```
var userChoice = prompt("Do you choose rock, paper or scissors?");
var computerChoice = Math.random();

// Sanity check. This is the result if there is no a tie, win or loss.
var userResult = 'You must choose either rock, paper or scissors.';

if (computerChoice < 0.34) {
    computerChoice = "rock";
} else if (computerChoice <= 0.67) {
    computerChoice = "paper";
} else {
    computerChoice = "scissors";
}

function compare(choice1, choice2) {
    if (choice1 === choice2) {
        userResult = "It is a tie!";
    } else if (choice1 === "rock") {
        if (choice2 === "scissors") {
            userResult = "You win! Rock smashes scissors";
        } else {
            userResult = "You lose! Paper covers rock";
        }
    } else if (choice1 === "paper") {
        if (choice2 === "rock") {
            userResult = "You win! Paper covers rock";
        } else {
            userResult = "You lose! Scissors cut paper";
        }
    } else if (choice1 === "scissors") {
        if (choice2 === "paper") {
            userResult = "You win! Scissors cut paper";
        } else {
            userResult = "You lose! Rock smashes paper";
        }
    }
    return userResult;
}

compare(userChoice, computerChoice);
```

I added a little sanity check for when someone tries to throw 'potato' or something that is not rock, paper or scissors. Also, made it clear **who** won or lost and why. Sorry, I couldn't resist.