# JS Error (class,interface, or enum expected)

Tags: javascript

I am new to JS and trying to make a Rock, Paper, Scissors Game...

It keeps on coming up with this error

```
error: class,interface, or enum expected
```

Here is my code:

```
function referee(){

    var training = {};

    function learn(winner,loser){
        if (!training[winner]) training[winner] = {};
        training[winner][loser]=1;
    }

    function judge(play1,play2){
        if (play1 === play2){ return "tie"; }
        return ( (training[play1][play2] === 1)? play1: play2 )+ "wins!";
    }

    function validate(choice) {
        return choice in training;
    }

    function choices() {
        return Object.keys(training);
    }

    return {
        "learn": learn,
        "judge": judge,
        "validAction": validate,
        "getChoices": choices
    };
}



var ref = referee();
ref.learn("rock","scissors");
ref.learn("paper","rock");
ref.learn("scissors","paper");

do {
   var userChoice = prompt("Do you choose rock, paper or scissors?");
} while(!ref.validAction(userChoice))

var choices = ref.getChoices(),
computerChoice = choices[Math.floor(Math.random()*choices.length)];

console.log("User Choice: " + userChoice); 
console.log("Computer Choice: " + computerChoice);
console.log(ref.judge(userChoice, computerChoice));
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [what wrong with this paper and rock mini game?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20477308/what-wrong-with-this-paper-and-rock-mini-game)

Comment: i see that you are using `referee` as a class while it isn't being interpret as a class. Please refer to [Introduction to OO Javascript programming](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Introduction_to_Object-Oriented_JavaScript) guide to understand the OO concept in js.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Object.keys(training);` is only supported in Chrome

Change

```
function choices() {
    return Object.keys(training);
}
```

to

```
function choices() {
   var keys = [];
   for(var key in this) keys.push(key);
   return keys;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of just placing the return at the end, you might want to make it a function. Right now your "ref" variable holds an array, since that's what the referee function returns.

I see Hitham S. AlQadheeb has beat me to the answer lol!